# How to change the column name just for the output?

Tags: php, sql

I need to change the name for this column in the output only:

```
function profile_display_hierarchy_fields($userid) {
global $OUTPUT, $DB;
$sql = "SELECT p.fullname as pos, o.fullname as org, u.id as manid,
            " . $DB->sql_fullname('u.firstname', 'u.lastname') . " AS fullname
            FROM {pos_assignment} pa
                LEFT JOIN {pos} p ON pa.positionid = p.id
                LEFT JOIN {org} o ON pa.organisationid = o.id
                LEFT JOIN {user} u ON u.id = pa.managerid
            WHERE pa.userid = ? AND pa.type = 1 ";

$record = $DB->get_record_sql($sql, array($userid), IGNORE_MULTIPLE);

//if (isset($record->pos)) {
echo '<tr>';
    echo html_writer::tag('td', get_string('position', 'totara_hierarchy'));
    echo html_writer::tag('td', $record->pos);
//}td

if (isset($record->org)) {
    //echo html_writer::tag('td', get_string('organisation', 'totara_hierarchy'));
   //echo html_writer::tag('td', $record->org);
}

//if (isset($record->manid)) {
    $manurl = html_writer::link(new moodle_url('/user/profile.php', array("id" => $record->manid)), $record->fullname);
echo '<tr>';
    echo html_writer::tag('td', get_string('manager', 'totara_hierarchy'));
    echo html_writer::tag('td', $manurl);
//}
```

}

I change 'manager` in last part to 'supervisor' but supervisor ends up as [[supevisor]] in the result. can I change the column name on just the output without [[ ]] showing. Thanks.

Comment: Where are you changing "manager" to "supervisor"?

Comment: to a table on screen. Manager ends up being a row description. i can get it to read supervisor but not without the double brackets around it